# How to make the loop with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'am trying to display `json` data with a loop.

I am getting the following results but don't know how to display them with loop.

```
[
    {"latitude":"23.046100780353495","longitude":"72.56860542227514"},
    {"latitude":"23.088427701737665","longitude":"72.49273109366186"},
    {"latitude":"23.061264193197644","longitude":"72.68224525381811"},
    {"latitude":"22.977212139977677","longitude":"72.52191352774389"},
    {"latitude":"23.002180435752084","longitude":"72.47590827872045"},
    {"latitude":"23.108638843843046","longitude":"72.49444770743139"}
]
```

I have created this loop:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var total = obj.length;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {

    console.log([i]);

}
```

and tried to display the results like this:

```
23.046100780353495,72.56860542227514
23.088427701737665,72.49273109366186
23.061264193197644,72.68224525381811
22.977212139977677,72.52191352774389
23.002180435752084,72.47590827872045
23.108638843843046,72.49444770743139
```

Comment: What do you see in your `console.log`?  That should help you get to the result you want.

Comment: Use `obj[i].latitude, obj[i].longitude`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

- `{}` parentheses are **objects**, you access properties like `object.property`.
- `[]` parentheses are **arrays**, you access elements by indexes `array[index]`.

In your particular case, this should do it:

```
var objects_array = JSON.parse(data); // This is an array of objects.
var total = objects_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var obj = objects_array[i]; // This is one object from the array.
    console.log( obj.latitude + ',' + obj.longitude ); // We access object properties using a dot.
}
```

Comment: In fairness, you can also access object properties like this, as well: `object["property"]`

Comment: @talemyn totally right. I just prefer to use dot notation to avoid getting confused ;)

Comment: As long as I'm not using a variable for the property, I'm the same way.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array already has default keys. So try something in the manner of:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
  console.log(value.latitude, value.longitude);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var total = obj.length;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    console.log(obj[i].latitude + ', ' + obj[i].longitude);
}
```

JSON values can be accessed using the `.dot` notation.

Here you have named an array of objects as `obj`. I would recommend renaming `obj` to a more descriptive name such as `coordinates` or `coordinatesArray`.